# How do I carry out high pass filtering on a csv file?

Tags: csv, highpass-filter

I have a csv file containing accelerometer data, and I would analyze it by applying a high pass filter to the data. Unfortunately I cannot seem to figure out how to do this in Excel, neither can I find a simple, free software that would allow me to do so.

Any ideas?

Below are graphs of the two data sets I would like to analyze (I can provide the csv if you think that would help). These are basically 3D linear acceleration magnitudes obtained from a phone plotted against time in milliseconds. I am trying to detect quick, sharp changes/spikes.

[image: Dataset 1]
[image: Dataset 2]

I can see there are some really low frequency components here (on the order of a few hertz), but I wouldn't be able to tell you what my frequency cutoff is, but I think I will find that out after a bit of experimentation once I am able to see the output - which is exactly why I need a quick and dirty way to test a couple of cuttoff frequencies in a HPF on this data.

Comment: How about posting some data samples with a description of the data and the parameters of the required filtration...

Comment: Good suggestion - give me a little while. I'll update the question with the details.

Comment: I would recommend R (http://www.r-project.org); it is free and can do what you want and it seems possible to use R from Excel (http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-million-ways-to-connect-r-and-excel/). If you want to know how you could tag your question with the R tag.

Comment: Hey @JanvanderLaan - I looked through the links you gave but I don't see any reference to R being able to carry out high pass filtering.

Comment: @PratikThaker the packages I linked to only show how R can be used from Excel. Inside R there a probably dozens of methods available (e.g. first search result on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105962/how-do-i-run-a-high-pass-or-low-pass-filter-on-data-points-in-r). For you application the R-package `Peaks` (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Peaks/index.html) also seems interesting. Importing a CSV-file into R is also quite simple.

Answer (score 3):

A simple IIR high pass filter for removing low frequency noise is easy to implement directly within an Excel spreadsheet.  You don't need to use Matlab, Octave or even VBA and for such an undemanding application you almost certainly don't need to learn the intricacies of FIR filter design.

new_hpf = (prev_hpf + new_sample - prev_sample) / (1 + time_constant/sample_period)

The method is demonstrated in an example spreadsheet at http://excelunusual.com/basic-filters-2/

If you want a sharper cut off you can try cascading another filter. Note that the phase response of a simple recursive filter is not linear, but if you are only interested in the magnitude of the data and simply want to remove a low frequency wander, then this should work fine.

Comment: This was a quick and complete solution for me, which is funny because the other answer says "No one here will provide you a complete solution".

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel VBA and implement an nth order FIR/IIR filter. I would recommend using a more powerful language like Python or C++ which can read the file and parse it for the values. You should also probably use an FIR filter as they are guaranteed to be stable and are simpler. Look here for information on digital filters - http://www-sigproc.eng.cam.ac.uk/foswiki/pub/Main/3F3/3F3__Digital_Signal_Processing_(DSP)_2015_Section_2.pdf.

This will explain everything you need to know to implement IIR and FIR filters. Basically you choose your poles and zeroes in the complex plane for a particular frequency response you desire based on your sampling rate. Eg if you are sampling at 500 Hz and you want to keep everything above 400 Hz only, you can put some zeroes below phase 4*pi/5 and magnitude maybe around 0.1. And maybe a pole (always within the unit circle) maybe at 4.5*pi/5. You then implement these poles and zeroes with an algorithm as shown in the lecture notes, there are different nethods, some more efficient (but more complex to understand) than others. But you will have to read the theory yourself or go to the signal processing stack exchange website.

Also, if you have access to MATLAB, it will do all of this for you in a few lines. But you will still need to understand the theory so you can place your poles and zeroes. If you don't have access or the £££ required for MATLAB, use Octave instead. See this Octave package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/signal/signal.pdf. It will give you one liners that can implement many types of filters, e.g. Butterworth or Chebyshev.

No one here will provide you a complete solution, we can just answer small technical problems you have on the way.

The bottom line: Learn the basics of filtering and then use MATLAB/Octave

Edit: I've done a bit of research and found out that you can use `scipy` in Python:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html

Design FIR filter:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html#scipy.signal.firwin

Implement IIR/FIR filter:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html#scipy.signal.lfilter

```
import scipy.signal
fir = scipy.signal.firwin2(11, [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]) #Design FIR Highpass filter, 11 is the filter order (higher = better quality but more computation, the first array is a sampling of frequency points (0 being 0 Hz and 1 being the Nyquist frequency) and the second array is the corresponding gain values at those points
x = [6, 3]*10
output = scipy.signal.lfilter(fir, [1], x)
print output
```

**Warning:** While the above method does work, it is difficult to get it to produce the actual desired frequency response from an arbitrary gain specification. This is because signal processing is complicated! If you just specify your magnitude response as a brick wall, you will get significant ripples in your stopband. I can't seem to get reasonable results using `scipy` as I've not had any experience with it. With the `firwin` method (which is a better idea if you don't know any signal processing), I can't figure out how to make it work as both the high pass and low pass FIRs seem to produce the same output.

I would recommend Octave, `fir1(40,0.7,'high')` produces a beautiful frequency response (try `freqz(fir1(400, 0.7, 'high'))`).

You can then use `fftfilt(fir1(400, 0.7, 'high'), x)` where `x` is your input.

Comment: Yea, I was kinda hoping to avoid having to read the csv file into a more powerful language and then implement a filter there, just to save the effort of coding the whole thing. But if that is the best way, then I'd like to know if there are existing libraries/packages/code that does something like this for me 'out of the box'. Do you know of any such solutions?

Comment: Excel VBA is the only way to do it if you don't want to leave Excel. In which case you cannot use a prebuilt library as I doubt one exists for VBA, so you will have to code it up yourself and read up on the notes I provided. Python may have some libraries in scipy for filtering. Basically you can't have it both ways.

Comment: And even if you use an out of the box solution, you need to understand the principles, otherwise your filter will never work properly. Like you need to understand how the sampling rate affects the characteristics of your filter.

Comment: Btw MATLAB will do everything for you out of the box but it is expensive so I doubted you have it. Maybe try octave. Also do a discrete Fourier transform to see the freq components so you know where to put the cut off

Comment: Yea MATLAB is way to expensive for something that is currently just a small side project. And if I have to code in VBA, I might as well just leave Excel and do this in Java which I'm more comfortable with. Which is kind of the path I'm inclined towards now. So I'm going to see if I can look up a Java implementation of a high pass filter - I'd be obliged if you or someone else can let me know if they know of a good one.

Comment: Octave looks good. Checking it out. Also, found a friend who has MATLAB. Going to see if I can commandeer that for a bit.

Comment: scipy is interesting. Appears quite powerful. Lemme see that too.

Comment: I made some mistakes in my example - I'll fix them