# Setting up a lowpass filter with 50 Hz in R without phase distortion?

Tags: r, lowpass-filter

I have collected eye-tracking data with 500 Hz sampling frequency. I have computed the velocity of the eye-movements and now I would like to apply a 50 Hz low pass filter to the velocity profiles (as have other researchers, for example Jainta, Hoormann, & Jaschinski (2007)).

I am struggeling to set up a 50 Hz lowpass filter in R. I tried using the package signal.

As I understood, when using a Butterworth filter with my sampling frequency of 500 Hz, I would have to use W = 0.2 to achieve a 50 Hz lowpass filter. Is the following correct?

```
bf <- butter(n = 1, w = 0.2, type = "low", plane = "z") 
y_filtered <- filter(bf, y)
```

However, this will result in a phase distortion as, for example, shown in this post:

[How do I run a high pass or low pass filter on data points in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105962/how-do-i-run-a-high-pass-or-low-pass-filter-on-data-points-in-r)

Also according to the answers in the linked post, I would have to use W = 0.4 to achieve a 50 Hz lowpass filter when using the function filtfilt to avoid phase distortion. Is that correct?

However, since in the documentations of filtfilt there is "... so this function needs some work yet - and is in the state of the year 2000 version of the Octave code." I would not like to use it if there is another option.

I considered using loess, but are unsure, which span would be equivalent to a 50 Hz filter? According to linked video, span is set to a proportion of the total number of data points. Is this also true in R?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vf7oJ6z2LCc

What would that mean in my case, how would I need to choose span?

Maybe there a other functions I would better use, of which I am not aware so far...

So, could someone help me with setting up a 50 Hz lowpass filter? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a super long signal (millions of samples, say), a simple FFT filter should do the job nicely.

First some example data

```
set.seed(1)

sf <- 500   # sampling frequency
ns <- 2000  # number of samples
cf <- 50    # cut-off frequency

f1 <- 43
f2 <- 50
f3 <- 55
f4 <- 81

s1 <- sin(seq(0, pi*2*(ns/sf)*f1, length.out=ns))
s2 <- sin(seq(0, pi*2*(ns/sf)*f2, length.out=ns) + pi/4)
s3 <- sin(seq(0, pi*2*(ns/sf)*f3, length.out=ns) + pi/3)
s4 <- sin(seq(0, pi*2*(ns/sf)*f4, length.out=ns))
n1 <- runif(ns, -0.2, 0.2) + runif(ns, -0.2, 0.2)

xx.o <- ts(s1 + s2, frequency=sf)
xx <- ts((xx.o + s3 + s4 + n1/10)/4, frequency=sf)

xx.o <- (xx.o - mean(xx.o))/2
xx <- xx - mean(xx)
```

Then we take the Fourier transform, null the upper bins, and reassemble with an inverse Fourier transform.

```
ft <- fft(xx)
lft <- length(ft)
b <- ns/(sf/cf)
ft[-c(1:b, (lft-b):lft)] <- 0

xx.lp <- Re(fft(ft, inv=TRUE))/lft

par(mfrow=c(2, 1), mar=c(3, 3, 0.2, 0.1), mgp=c(2, 0.6, 0), xpd=FALSE)
spectrum(xx, main="", ylim=c(1e-15, 0.1), sub="")
spectrum(xx.lp, main="", ylim=c(1e-15, 0.1), sub="")
```

[image]

As you see, no phase shift

```
par(mfrow=c(3, 1), mar=c(3, 3, 0.2, 0.1), mgp=c(2, 0.6, 0), xpd=FALSE)
plot(xx[1:(sf/2)], type="l", ylim=c(-1, 1))
plot(xx.lp[1:(sf/2)], type="l", ylim=c(-1, 1))
plot(xx.o[1:(sf/2)], type="l", ylim=c(-1, 1))
```

[image]