# Low-pass fltering of a matrix

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a low-pass filter in R, to clean a "dirty" data matrix.

I did a google search, came up with a dazzling range of packages. Some apply to 1D signals (time series mostly, e.g. [How do I run a high pass or low pass filter on data points in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105962/how-do-i-run-a-high-pass-or-low-pass-filter-on-data-points-in-r) ); some apply to images. However I'm trying to filter a plain R data matrix. The image filters are the closest equivalent, but I'm a bit reluctant to go this way as they typically involve (i) installation of more or less complex/heavy solutions (imageMagick...), and/or (ii) conversion from matrix to image.

Here is sample data:

```
r<-seq(0:360)/360*(2*pi)
x<-cos(r)
y<-sin(r)

z<-outer(x,y,"*")
noise<-0.3*matrix(runif(length(x)*length(y)),nrow=length(x))

zz<-z+noise

image(zz)
```

What I'm looking for is a filter that will return a "cleaned" matrix (i.e. something close to z, in this case).

I'm aware this is a rather open-ended question, and I'm also happy with pointers ("have you looked at package so-and-so"), although of course I'd value sample code from users with experience on signal processing !

Thanks.

Comment: possibly related ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105962/how-do-i-run-a-high-pass-or-low-pass-filter-on-data-points-in-r

Comment: This is actually one of the things I found (--> edit). From what I understand, package ```signal``` works only in 1D, or did I miss something ?

Comment: @jmoyen You can always `apply` functions to vectors in R see the answer below fitting a polynomial regression to each vector

Comment: Technically true, but I'm not sure a series of 1D filter applied to each row/col are the same as a 2D filter. If you filter by line, for instance, a line of anomalously high values would not be filtered out by your 1D filter applied to all lines. On the other hand, since it would be a high frequency feature (in the other direction) it would be filtered out by a proper low pass, operating on the total "distance".

Comment: And yes you are right, the same issue applies to the solution below, I didn't notice...

Answer (score 1):

One option may be using a non-linear prediction method and getting the fitted values from the model.

For example by using a polynomial regression, we can predict the original data as the purple one,

[image]

By following the same logic, you can do the same thing to all columns of the `zz` matrix as,

```
predictions <- matrix(, nrow = 361, ncol = 0)

for(i in 1:ncol(zz)) {

    pred <- as.matrix(fitted(lm(zz[,i]~poly(1:nrow(zz),2,raw=TRUE))))
    predictions <- cbind(predictions,pred)  

}
```

Then you can plot the predictions,

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))

image(z,main="Original")
image(zz,main="Noisy")
image(predictions,main="Predicted")
```

[image]

Note that, I used a polynomial regression with degree 2, you can change the degree for a better fitting across the columns. Or maybe, you can use some other powerful non-linear prediction methods (maybe SVM, ANN etc.) to get a more accurate model.

Comment: not bad at all ! I was looking initially for a "proper" low pass filter, seems more appropriate, but this is a good proxy if nothing else...