# Is there a function to filter velocity-time data with a butterworth filter and rolling average in R?

Tags: r, filter, butterworth

Essentially I have a time column and a velocity column and need to filter data that was exported from a radar gun. This should be simple but cant seem to find the function

Comment: Please share a snippet of your data to make this question reproducible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105962/how-do-i-run-a-high-pass-or-low-pass-filter-on-data-points-in-r

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/signal/signal.pdf

Comment: Thank you @JonSpring. The following is just what I needed:   library(signal)

bf <- butter(2, 1/50, type="low")
x <- data$Time
b <- filter(bf, data$Speed)
plot(x, b, lwd = 5, col = "green")

data$vel <- b

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.